# Expo - React Native: Firebase Phone Number Authentication is failing

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I need help. I am trying to send a verification code with phone number authentication in [EXPO](https://docs.expo.io/) and It works well in development. But I don't know why the same code is not working in production. I am getting this error,

> verifyphonenumber failed: second argument “applicationVerifier” must be an implementation of firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier

The `FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal` is not showing up when I click to send the verification code. I think, it is failing in the second argument of `verifyPhoneNumber()` but I can’t see how I can correct `this.recaptchaVerifier.current` using the [Doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-recaptcha/). Here is my code

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View,  TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import config from '../../firebase.config';
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from 'expo-firebase-recaptcha';
import {ToastError, ToastSuccess} from '../../utils/Toast';
import styles from './styles';


class PhoneAuthScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            phoneNumber: '',
        },
        this.recaptchaVerifier = React.createRef();
    }

    onChangeText(key, value) {
        this.setState({
            [key]: value
        })
    }

    signInWithPhoneNumber = async () => {
        const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
        const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
        try {
            const verificationId = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber, this.recaptchaVerifier.current);

            this.setState({ verificationId: verificationId });
            ToastSuccess('Verification code has been sent to your phone.');

        } catch (err) {
            ToastError(err.message);
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.verifyPage}>
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.telSection}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.telInput}
                            placeholder='+1 201-555-0123'
                            placeholderTextColor='#080040'
                            keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                            returnKeyType='done'
                            autoCapitalize='none'
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            secureTextEntry={false}
                            ref='PhoneInput'
                            autoCompleteType="tel"
                            value={this.state.phoneNumber}
                            onChangeText={(val) => {
                                    this.onChangeText('phoneNumber', val)
                                }
                            }
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>


                <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal 
                   ref={this.recaptchaVerifier} 
                   firebaseConfig={config} 
                />
           

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.confirmBtn} onPress={this.signInWithPhoneNumber}>
                        <Text style={styles.confirmText}>Send Verification Code</Text>       
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        )
  };
}

export default PhoneAuthScreen;
```